# Can't get unique values joining two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, distinct-values

I have 2 tables that I need to join and select the unique rows from.  Here is a sample of my data: (there are more columns)

```
tbl1:
MB# MBName  PCCNo_PRI   Primary_IP       PCCNo_SEC          Secondary_IP    ID
100  name    0               10.1.9.10       30              10.1.9.10       1 
103  name3   17              10.1.9.27       47              10.1.9.67       4
403  name13  17              10.1.9.27       47              10.1.9.67       14
```

tbl2:

```
RTU PCC#_PRI    PCC#_SEC    STATION ADDRESS
15  0           30          6
52  12          42          1
53* 17          47          1
54  18          48          1
63  9           39          2
69* 17          47          2
```

I need to join the two tables and get the unique RTU(s) in tbl2 for a given MB# in tbl1.
Query =

```
SELECT t1.MB#,t2.RTU,t2.[Device Manufacturer],t2.PCC#_PRI,t2.PCC#_SEC,t2.[STATION ADDRESS] 
INTO C300_RTU_MASTERBLK_Map
FROM mbm_PCDIMasterBlk_tbl as t1, dbo.WOA_PCC_Conn_tbl as t2
WHERE t1.PCCNo_PRI = t2.PCC#_PRI
```

I am getting duplicate rows for tbl2 53 and 69 (* above).  53 ends up with 2 entries; one to 103 and one 403 (69 gets same).   How can I query this for unique RTU(s) to MB#?

Comment: Can you post what your results should be? How do you decide which row you need. for ex for pccNo_pri = 17, which one you need 53 or 69? what is the logic?

Comment: If you want the complete set of combos of `RTU` and `MB#`, then your results are correct.  Your results would be (`RTU`, `PCCNo_PRI', 'MB#') : (53, 17, 103), (53, 17, 403), (69, 17, 103), (69, 17, 403).  Since your data clearly contains combos where the same RTU applies to mulitple MB#, what is your actual problem and how would you identify which rows are "wrong"?

Comment: Good question.  I think you have exposed my problem.  I know what it should be but couldn't see my flaw until you guys pointed it out.  Let me see if I can redo one of these tables.

Comment: The results should be: 53 ->103 (only) & 69 -> 403 (only)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The duplicate rows appears because you join on "17" which gives 2 rows on each side

Then, as it stands, you can't with that SELECT list.
How do you decide which `t1.MB#` you want for the t2 columns?

There is no secondary JOIN column that I can see. 
So the best you can get is use MAX (or MIN) to pick either 403 or 103.

```
SELECT
   MAX(t1.MB#) AS MB#,
   t2.RTU,t2.[Device Manufacturer],t2.PCC#_PRI,t2.PCC#_SEC,t2.[STATION ADDRESS] 
INTO C300_RTU_MASTERBLK_Map
FROM 
   dbombm_PCDIMasterBlk_tbl as t1
   JOIN
   dbo.WOA_PCC_Conn_tbl as t2 ON t1.PCCNo_PRI = t2.PCC#_PRI
GROUP BY
   t2.RTU,t2.[Device Manufacturer],t2.PCC#_PRI,t2.PCC#_SEC,t2.[STATION ADDRESS]
```

Comment: Good code, it eliminates the duplicates but does not give the correct result.  53 & 69 get assigned to MB#403.  53 should go to 103 and 69 to 403.  I see the question about how to determine what the results should be.  In trying to answer that I realize that really 53 would only get assigned to 103 because of the order of the row processing not because of any logical assignment.

Comment: This is the answer.  I went back and fixed tbl1 (found an error in how I was populating the data) and then this query worked.  Thanks gbn.